# VBA CODE to replace cell content based on conditions in 2 different columns

Tags: vba, replace, cell

I have a problem on the code that I am writing. I have researched multiple websites that has similar coding scenario like this, some of them gave some insight on how to write this code but it only does half the job.

So in Col B, I have a list of Routing guides: `ABC, DEF, GHI`
In Col C, I also have an array of information: `VVV, WWW, XXX, YYY, ZZZ`.

If it says `ABC` in Col B and Col C shows `WWW`, `XXX` or `YYY`, I need to replace Col C with `UUU`. Below is my code and I appreciate your help in advance! Thank you!

```
Sub Replace_cell ()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim x As Long

'Filter ABC  only on Routing Column B

Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
        "ABC"

'Find WWW, XXX, YYY in Col C and replace them with UUU

fndList = Array("WWW", "XXX", "YYY")
rplcList = ("UUU")

'Loop through each item in Array lists

For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
    'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sht.Cells.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _     
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next sht

Next x

End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @Ambie for editing that. Not sure why it looked iffy when i uploaded my code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do the filtering for each worksheet in turn, and then find/replace, so the nesting order (inner/outer) of your loops should be reversed. Also as you said you want to replace in `Column C`, not all cells of the worksheet.

```
Sub Replace_colC()
  Dim sht As Worksheet, x As Long, fndList, rplcList

  fndList = Array("WWW", "XXX", "YYY")
  rplcList = Array("UUU", "UUU", "UUU")
  ' though replacement values are the same, they could be different

  For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
   'Filter ABC on Routing Column B
    sht.Cells.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="ABC"

    'Loop through each item in Array lists and replace
    For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
      sht.UsedRange.Columns("C").Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next x
    sht.AutoFilterMode = False
  Next sht
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the updated code! I tried to run it but the loop and replace statement did not replace those in the fndlist with UUU. When i run the codes thru F8, it only filters out everything and the only thing left are the headers and does nothing after that. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @jackie, you say *"it only filters out everything and the only thing left are the headers "*, that means you dont have any `"ABC"` cells in column B? What the code does is first find `ABC` in column B and in those rows if cell `C` is among the `fndlist` it replaces it. This is what your OP states and it is fully tested.

Comment: Yaaaaay! I tried the code again and it worked perfectly today! Thank you very much for your help! ( I think i was just exhausted yesterday after going out for a run :D) have a great day!

Comment: Glad you showed me how to accept the answer. I was looking for that option since I just joined Stackoverflow recently. I turned it green now. :)